# Taskkill can't end process but taskmanager can

Tags: powershell, permissions, cmd.exe, task-manager, tasks

I recently found out something interesting: I can't kill tasks with `taskkill` but the **Task-Manager** kills them. I can end the process with the task manager just fine, but when I try it with `taskkill`, it gives me permission denied.

```
PS C:\Users\user> taskkill /PID 8640 /F
ERROR: The process with PID 8640 could not be stopped.
Reason: Permission denied
```

Anyone knows what is going on here and how to fix that problem?

PS: I know I can kill it with an administrative shell, but that is **not** the solution I am searching for. If the task manager can do it without permission, taskkill should do it as well.

Comment: Which process is PID 8640? Are you running CMD as Admin?

Comment: The fact you can kill the same process ID by elevating the terminal shell suggests the process you are attempting to kill is a system process.

Comment: I assume it's the integrity level of the process you are trying to kill is either high, system or installer? If you use Process Explorer and add the Integrity column, do you see that the TaskMgr.exe process is High but Taskkill.exe as a child of cmd or powershell (not elevated) is running at Medium.

Comment: The process I'm trying to kill is not a system process

Comment: Don't know why this question is closed, but nevertheless the answer is `powershell "Get-Process | Where Name –Like whatever | Stop-Process"`, which does not require admin privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taskkill is a program that needs administrative privileges to kill a task. If you start command prompt as admin and run the same command, it will succesfully kill the task.

Accessing Task Manager is also a process that requires administrative privileges, which is, when you access Task Manager, the first thing you see is an elevation prompt asking for permissions. If you click no on that prompt, Task Manager does not open.

So in your following statement:

> If the task manager can do it without permission, taskkill should do it as well.

No, task manager cannot. You have to give permission the moment you open Task Manager.

Comment: I have recorded a video that shows the Task manager opens with High priority without Admin rights. [Video Proof](https://streamable.com/25ostu) I haven't configured anything about that.

Comment: Are you on Windows 11 maybe? Its possible Windows 11 changed behavior that always launches task manager as admin without requiring a security prompt. Also, what happens if you start task manager by right-clicking the taskbar, task manager, or use its hotkey: CTRL-SHIFT-ESC? Do you get an UAC prompt then?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows 11. But I had the same problem on Windows 10 too. It doesn't matter how it starts my task manager, UAC never pops up.

Comment: But what worries me the most, is I can create admin level tasks with the task manager **without** UAC showing up. So it is possible to completely bypass UAC. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/P57G5pq.png) picture.

Comment: I have no idea then. Your problem obviously is that Task manager runs as admin somehow while it shouldn't, and its not a problem with taskkill

Comment: I think I found the cause: [auto elevate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965411/how-does-task-manager-elevate-without-uac-prompt). But do you know how a task started without admin privileges requires them to end it?

Comment: Normally if you run taskkill without privileges and without the /f parameter, it will ask the app to close, similarly as how you press the close button. But if the program refuses, for example it is busy and doesn't want to close just yet, it may allow to cancel the closing procedure. The /force parameter overrides this and forcefully closes any program regardless if the program itself wants or not. This action requires elevated permissions however.